# How can I change a route in Rails 3 based on user login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm curious if it's possible to send a Rails 3 application to one website if someone lands on the site as a guest and another website if someone lands on the site as a user.

Is this done in routes? Is this done in the controller-tier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using sessions. They work like this:

```
session[:any_key] = any value (though it should be small, think database id, instead of entire model)
```

Most people use session[:user_id]

Resources:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

http://railscasts.com/episodes/21-super-simple-authentication

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html

Comment: So I can use a session, and then based on the session value define my default route?

Comment: Routes are defined as all the possible places you can go in your application. What you want is to be able to figure out which of those places to go based upon the browser session value. So you can simply set up a redirect_to (i.e. if session[:old_user] then redirect_to dashboard_path else redirect_to other_path end).

Comment: You may also want to handle this in the views alone. So put everything in your dashboard's view, but then set up conditionals around what content to display should the user be returning. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I was already using sessions as part of AuthLogic, and so now I just need to add the appropriate redirect.

I'll go ahead and code this puppy up. Thanks!